# wp_nav_menu with WP as pure CMS

Tags: menus, cms

I'm trying to use WP as a pure backend CMS for my site. I've got a few pages setup in WP e.g. About, Main Page, Sample Page and I can display the content on my own php pages by using `get_page_by_title`.
However when I try to use `wp_nav_menu` to generate the navigation elements, the links generated are in the form of `www.example.com/wordpress/?page=2`.

I know I can change WP to use nice permalinks to get `www.example.com/wordpress/about` but I'd like to customise it further so that the link would read `www.example.com/about` e.g. skip the wordpress install location.

Is this possible and how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know I can change WP to use nice permalinks to get `www.example.com/wordpress/about` but I'd like to customise it further so that the link would read `www.example.com/about` e.g. skip the wordpress install location.

**Rather than "skipping the location", point your domain *to the location*.

Or install WP to your root, respectively.**

You *could* obviously do some rewriting as well, but why go the long way if the solution is simple?

As for pretty permalinks:
However you go about it, this is a necessary step on the way.

Hence set your permalink structure to something along the lines of `/%year%/%postname%/`.

There used to be performance downsides to using just `/%postname%/`, which have been [fixed with 3.3](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/18541), but I tend to still not use that only.
Pages will ignore `/%year%/` anyway. And should you ever decide to use the blog functionality as well, I don't find a year structure hurtful. Up to you.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've just added some redirects to the .htaccess. I'd like to keep all the WP stuff in a separate directory because I'm a bit OCD.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with permalink settings in wp admin. (/wp-admin/options-permalink.php)
Set your permalink structure to Post name or custom structure with %postname%

Comment: I'm 99% sure that won't work as the /wordpress/ bit of it isn't part of the permalink that can be modified ( at least on my install) via that options page.

Comment: your wordpress is at main domain or in wordpress folder ?

Comment: In wordpress folder can see here http://i.imgur.com/nYGdNjY.png?1 only the bit after the wordpress directory is editable on custom structure.

Comment: You can then use htaccess to rewrite urls